# How do I use window.location.href in codesandbox.io?

Tags: window.location, codesandbox

I'd like to use `window.location.href` in the tool codesandbox.io.  This is because I want to do a test with a hard page load occurring.  I'm running into an issue however.

```
location.href = "http://www.google.com"
```

I get this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-bird-nyvfi' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.google.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**Example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/locationhref-usage-nyvfi (see `src/index.ts` and open Dev Console)

How do I accomplish this the ability to *simulate a page load*, in the fake virtual browser?

Comment: Go to an HTTPS page like `https://www.google.com/` I guess

Comment: Thanks.  However I received a new error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible once the security criteria are met; which is limiting.

- Use HTTPS (Avoid mixed content)
- Use same origin

Thus this works:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.codesandbox.io/docs";
```